# How can I connect to Windows XP via RDP without opening a local session first?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machines, remote-desktop

I have a Windows XP Pro virtual machine hosted in Hyper-V (on Windows 8 Pro). Since the native Hyper-V connection window has very limited features (e.g. no clipboard support), I use RDP to connect to the VM. My problem is that the RDP connection doesn't work until I open a local session on the VM. I suspect that a required service isn't started until a session is opened, but I don't know which one.

How can I enable RDP as soon as the VM starts, without needing to open a local session first?

Comment: If this question is off-topic on Server Fault, where should I post it? Certainly not on Stack Overflow, and Super User doesn't really seem right for it either. Server Fault is the best fit IMO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it. I just needed to change the startup type for the "Terminal Services" service from "Manual" to "Automatic".